# Android App XML Parsing Error

Tags: android, xml

I am using a Java class to import data to my app from a .csv file. I found some examples online, and this is what they seem to do. However, it's showing the error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix. The research I've done on this indicates that it is usually a spelling error. If it is, I can't find it. Here is the section where I am having the problem.

```
<provider android:name="com.ATS_Boxes.ContentProvider.class" 
android:authorities="ContentProvider"></provider>
```

Comment: <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">Drop Boxes</string>
 
 <provider android:name="com.ATS_Boxes.ContentProvider.class" 
 android:authorities="ContentProvider"></provider>
 
 <string name="fill_prompt">Choose a fill level</string>
  <string name="note_prompt">Notes. Choose more than one if necessary.</string>
  <string name="submit">Submit</string> 
</resources>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to declare a [`provider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) in an Android resource file - that isn't possible. You can only declare providers in your project's manifest file ([`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), in the root directory of your project).

Also, although I'm not sure if it makes any difference, the first line in the xml code you provided as comment reads:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
```

That looks like it's commented out. Normally it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

post the entire XML file.

My guess is that you do not have the 'android' namespace declared so its puking when it's parsing the attributes android:name and android:authorities